# ¿Alguien sabe como solucionar el error al intentar instalar la libreria libcurl4-openssl-dev en ParrotSecurity?

Tags: ubuntu

Intenté poner `sudo apt-get install -f libcurl4-openssl-dev` y `sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev`, pero me sale el siguiente error.

> sudo apt-get install -f libcurl4-openssl-dev
>
> Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
>
> Creando árbol de dependencias... Hecho
>
> Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
>
> No se pudieron instalar algunos paquetes. Esto puede significar que
> usted pidió una situación imposible o, si está usando la distribución
> inestable, que algunos paquetes necesarios aún no se han creado o se
> han sacado de «Incoming».
>
> La siguiente información puede ayudar a resolver la situación:
>
> Los siguientes paquetes tienen dependencias incumplidas:
> libcurl4-openssl-dev : Depende: libcurl4 (= 7.74.0-1.3+deb11u1) pero 7.82.0-2~bpo11+1 va a ser instalado
> E: No se pudieron corregir los problemas, usted ha retenido paquetes rotos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me sucedió lo mismo, desinstale el libcurl4

```
sudo apt-get remove libcurl4
```

y luego instale el libcurl4-openssl-dev de nuevo

```
sudo apt install libcurl4-openssl-dev
```